# insert into database with dynamic form with javascript (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I build an app but I found new problem, I want to insert multiple data using javascript to add more form dynamically (then insert into table). Okay in my FIGURE, number 1,2,3 that's clear. But when I insert into the table , it can't succesfully. (number 4 is my function to insert data, but all of may form  cannot insert (number 5) , only 1 data can insert ). what's wrong ? thanks

[FIGURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1iBo.jpg)

Comment: whats your Question??

Comment: You need to update last change field??

Comment: Example: when I add more form -> 10 form, I will insert 10 data's, but now, I only can insert 1 data. I guess I got wrong in my count($_POST). But what?

Answer (score 1):

use `for loop` like this, your $_POST must be under loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_REQUEST['heading']); $i++) {
                    $heading = $_POST["heading"][$i];
                    $address = $_POST["address"][$i];
                    $array_addmore[$i] =
                        array(
                            "heading" => urlencode($heading),
                            "address" => urlencode($address)
                        );
                }
```

Comment: I got an error like 
A Database Error Occurred

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: C:\wamp\www\SMU\system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1174

Comment: what is your update statement ?